# Difference Between @singleton and @injectable and @inject in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, typescript-generics

I tried to write a code using @singleton decorator and @injectable decorator and @inject decorator using typescript its working fine. but why to use this decorator and what is the difference in three decorators.

Comment: What is the framework or library you are using?

Comment: I am using typescript

Comment: typescript doesn't provide built-in decorators (`@singleton`, `@injectable`, etc). I suppose you're using inversify.js, or angular which has integrated inversify.js.

Comment: This question is too general, needs more focus. First try google "inverse of control", "dependency injection" to learn more about the concept. My two cent is that if you don't know what are they yet, you probably don't need them now.